# Background-colour of a column in excel is not changing

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change the colour of my column 'Speed' in excel wherever the value is 100 but it is not working just reading from the excel file and generating another excel file. Below is my code.

Excel-File has 6X Column 6X Rows (starting from 0) where row no 1 and 2 are blank and the
column names are ( Interface , Description, Encapsulation, IP ,Mask, Speed, Duplex)

```
import pandas as pd
import styleframe
import openpyxl
import numpy as np
import os



SPath=r'C:\Users\Excel-File'

File_List=os.listdir(SPath)
for X in File_List:
   
  SF=X
  df=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(SPath, SF))
  
  df.style.applymap([lambda x :'background-colour:green' if x is '100' else 'background-colour:red'],subset='Speed')
  df.style.to_excel('styled.xlsx',engine='openpyxl',index=False)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSqN3.jpg)

Comment: Are you using `styleframe`? your code imports it but the code you showed does not use it

Comment: I just imported it in my code but it is not used anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Speed':[100,200,100], 'col':list('abc')})

 #assign output to styled variable
 #remove u from text colour
styled = df.style.applymap(lambda x :'background-color:green' if x == 100 else 'background-color:red',subset=['Speed'])

#write to file styled
styled.to_excel('styled.xlsx',engine='openpyxl',index=False)
```

Comment: Hi Jezreal , i tried with your suggested change but still it is not working.

Comment: @Sharique - if change `100` to `'100'` same problem?

Comment: ..there is no error while generating the output excel file but not highlighting the 'Speed' column with specified value.

Comment: @Sharique - I create sample data and solution was changed, can you test?

Comment: Hi Jezreal , yes it is working with your given values but how will it work on the values in a file like in my case i am reading content from a excel file on which i am trying to highlight the column with specified value in a specified column.

Comment: @Sharique - what is `print (df['Speed'].head().tolist())` ? Do you test `100` value?

Comment: @Jazreal - the ouput of print (df['Speed'].head().tolist()) from your code is [100, 200, 100]

Comment: @Sharique - I think with your data. Because if failed my tested solution problem is in your data.

Comment: @Jazrel- the output of print (df['Speed'].head().tolist()) on my code is    [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]

Comment: @Sharique - then not idea, I test your data and working perfectly. Not typo `colour` ? It is necessary `color` (remove u)

Comment: @Jezreal - i have corrected the typo still it is not highlighting the value in column.What is the version of your python ( mine is 3.7.0 with anaconda platform )

Comment: @Sharique what is your pandas version? tested in `pandas 1.2.4`

Comment: Thanks Jezreal for your help- not sure why on my system /python platform the code is not giving expected output.

Comment: @Sharique - sample data from my answer working well? Or failed too?

Comment: @Jazreal , your sample data / code is working without any issue on my system /python platform but my shared code is not working .